# Reassigning Smart Pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, glib, gtkmm

Generally speaking do smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr` and `Glib::RefPtr` delete their object when reassigned to point at another object, given they are the only pointers holding that given object (obviously implied in case of `std::unique_ptr`)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For `unique_ptr::reset`, [unique.ptr.single.modifiers]/4:

> *Effects*: assigns `p` to the stored pointer, and then **if the old value of the stored pointer, `old_p`, was not equal to `nullptr`, calls
>   `get_deleter()(old_p)`**.

Or the move assignment operator, `operator=(unique_ptr&& u)` in [unique.ptr.single.asgn]/2:

> Transfers ownership from `u` to `*this` as if **by calling
>   `reset(u.release())`** followed by `get_deleter() = std::forward<D>(u.get_deleter())`.

<sub>(Equivalent for the other assignment operator template)</sub>

---

For `shared_ptr`, reassignment is a little bit different. `shared_ptr` will never destroy a referenced object when it's not the last remaining one owning it, so let's assume that is given.
`shared_ptr::reset(Y*)` specifies in [util.smartptr.shared.mod]/3:

> *Effects*: Equivalent to `shared_ptr(p).swap(*this)`.

But clearly the temporary gets destroyed at the end of the function call, destroying the hold object (if applicable).
 That is the same behavior `operator=(shared_ptr<> const&)` has, [util.smartptr.shared.assign]/1 and 4:

> *Effects*: Equivalent to `shared_ptr(r).swap(*this)`.

… move assignment operator (template), `r` is `shared_ptr<>&&`:

> *Effects*: Equivalent to `shared_ptr(std::move(r)).swap(*this)`.

If `*this` was the last owning the object, then now the temporary is - which will be destroyed inside.

---

For `Glib::RefPtr` the scenario is similar to `shared_ptr`: The copy assignment operator (and an assignment operator template) are defined with the same semantics. If the current `RefPtr` is assigned to something else, the currently hold objects reference counter is decremented and its destroyed if the resulting counter value is zero.

Comment: RefPtr<Something> something = getSomething(); something = getSomethingElse(); works fine. You shouldn't need to use RefPtr::swap(). Of course the reassignment here just decreases the reference on the first Something rather than deleting it. It's a reference-counting _shared_ smartpointer.

Comment: @murrayc I must have misread the documentation the first time I went over it. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

For [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) the answer is yes:

> The **object is destroyed and its memory deallocated when either of the
>   following happen**s:
>
> - unique_ptr managing the object is destroyed
> - **unique_ptr managing the object is assigned another pointer via operator= or reset().**
>
> The object is destroyed using a potentially user-supplied deleter by
>   calling Deleter(ptr). The deleter calls the destructor of the object
>   and dispenses the memory.